# Faster to parse data from session or pass parameter through views and controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to make my page load as fast as possible.

I have a large List of objects (about 10,000 records).

The web page is built up of around 15 partials.

Would it theoretically be faster to pass the list of objects through each View and controller using model (not using viewbag), or to parse the data from a Session["data"] entry?